# jQuery UI is disabling widgets - no idea why

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Strange problem: I'm using jQuery UI with Rails 3.2, and some of the widgets are coming up with "ui-state-disabled", and there is nowhere in my code or CSS that I'm causing that to happen.  For example, I create a slider widget as follows (coffeescript):

```
el.slider
    min: parseFloat(el.attr("min"))
    max: parseFloat(el.attr("max"))
    value: parseFloat(el.attr("value"))
    step: 0.5
    slide: (e, ui) ->
      [ ...do stuff...]
```

And here's what I get in the browser:

```
<div class="sliderDisplay ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget
ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-slider-disabled ui-state-disabled"    
min="2.0" max="20.0" value="4.0" aria-disabled="false">
```

I tried adding the option "disabled: false" to the call to slider(), but it didn't have any effect.  Note that aria-disabled is "false", which seems strange - I would think that this attribute would be in agreement with the ui-state-disabled class.

I have the same problem with the close button in the dialog titlebar.  It is also ui-state-disabled and will not respond to clicks.  Again, I'm opening it normally, and I haven't extended these widget classes in any way.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does your rails app load jQuery UI? You can confirm whether jQuery UI load or not by checking **Sources** tab of Chrome Developer Tool.

Comment: Yes, it sure does.  The widgets actually work - sort of.  For example, the dialog pops up as it should, but the close button is disabled.  The sliders work, but because they have the "ui-state-disabled" class, they have CSS opacity: 0.35 applied.  I can override this, obviously, but it would be hacky.  I'd like to know what's causing this to happen.